# how to check if Prettify is loaded

Tags: javascript, google-code-prettify

I'm only loading the script if `<pre class="prettyprint">` exists. I found that to initiate Prettify, you need to use `prettyPrint();`.

However, on pages that don't load the script, I get a Javascript error. Is there a way to test if Prettify is loaded, then run... else do nothing?

Comment: Update: the version as-of today (see comment date) needs this: `PR.prettyPrint()` to re-run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can test for it like this:

```
if (window.prettyPrint) {
    prettyPrint();
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Shorter than the `if (typeof prettyPrint == 'function')` solution I was using.

Comment: @gavsiu well , yours is better.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
function getElementsByClassName(className) {
if (document.getElementsByClassName) { 
    return document.getElementsByClassName(className); }
else { return document.querySelectorAll('.' + className); } }

window.onload = function() {
    if (getElementsByClassName('prettyprint').length) {
        /* element exists */
    } else { /* element not exists */ }
}
```

[EDIT] Ooops, you asked for the function existance, my bad :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to call `prettyPrint` anymore.

https://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/wiki/GettingStarted says

> ## Auto-Loader
>
> You can load the JavaScript and CSS for prettify via one URL
>
> ```
> <script src="https://google-code-prettify.googlecode.com/svn/loader/run_prettify.js"></script>
> ```
>
> will load the entire system and schedule the prettifier to run on page load. There are a variety of additional options you can specify (as CGI arguments) to configure the runner.
>
> ...

Comment: When I load a self hosted version of run_prettify.js, it calls the css file from Google Code, not from my own server. I don't want to rely on an alternate server unless I can make it work with a fallback to local.